# SQL Server Optimization: better to use "NOT NULL" or ">0"?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

In SQL Server 2012 I have a nullable INT column which, when it has a value, the value is greater than 0.  So for my purposes these two statements deliver identical results:

```
...WHERE MyColumn IS NOT NULL;
...WHERE MyColumn > 0;
```

My question is, as a rule, is one or the other more efficient?  Assume the column is indexed correctly.

Comment: Both does not be same, of your column has value -1 then it is valid number and first condition evaluates true and second evaluates false.

Comment: I realize both are not the same, but for my purposes they are the same.  I'm only interested in records where the value is > 0.

Comment: 1.  These are two completely separate conditions that are *not* equivalent.  2.  If these just so happen to be equivalent given the data you have, this is some sort of extreme micro-optimization that you really shouldn't be concerned with.  Use the `WHERE` clause that makes the most sense with your query.

Comment: Then > 0 would be more efficient.   One condition and nulls are omitted

Comment: @TomRegan If you're only interested in records where the value is `> 0`, then use `WHERE MyColumn > 0`.  Doing anything else will make for a horrible parsing experience for anyone else that has to read your queries.  Optimization on this level is irrelevant.

Comment: If you have an index and you are selecting only that column then both the options will do INDEX SEEK or INDEX SCAN, if you are selecting other attributes obviously it does rid lookup or key lookpup or completely it might not even use your index and use full scan depends on the selectivity of the columns. Hence I do not see any difference in performance while evaluating the predicate. If you have a filtered index which has the records which is not  NULL then there will be a difference in IO because of number of reads in the records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an index and you are selecting only that column then both the options will do INDEX SEEK or INDEX SCAN, if you are selecting other attributes obviously it does rid lookup or key lookpup or completely it might not even use your index and use full scan depends on the selectivity of the columns. Hence I do not see any difference in performance while evaluating the predicate.

If you have a filtered index which has the records which is not NULL then there will be a difference in IO because of number of reads in the records

Comment: Thank you @Kannan, we just migrated from SQL Server 2005, I'm still not used to considering filtered indexes, but that is exactly what I need to use here.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `WHERE MyColumn > 0` because it is crystal clear as condition and it is self documented.

On the other hand `WHERE MyColumn IS NOT NULL` also is clear but in your case it hides a special logic that is nowhere documented. You EXPECT that every not null value is a positive integer although the  value domain of column is integer. For everyone else this is not clear.

I don't think that there would be any performance issues. I think that sometimes we over analyze some things.